# Get "this" object of a Backbone View Outside of the Initialize Function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to access the this object returned in the initialize function of a backbone view.  In my initialize function I will

```
console.log(this)
```

and it will return an object for that view.  When I access the view directly through my namespace architecture like:

```
console.log(mysite.some.namespace.View)
```

I get the following returned:

```
function (){a.apply(this,arguments)}
```

How can I have access to the the "this" object outside of logging it in my initialize function?

Comment: Store the `new mysite.some.namespace.View` value somewhere.

Comment: Do you need to access a function or property of your View object or you are trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short.  That worked.